# AndEngine Onscreen controls

Tags: andengine

I wish to create Onscreen controls in my game, but i don't how to create Onscreen controls.

My doubts are:

1. How to create OnScreen Control?
2. Where should the OnScreen Controls be implemented in our game project?
3. Types of OnScreen Controls?

Now I am creating this game. I have one ball but I wish to create `Left`, `Right`, `Up` and `Down` move activities. which controls are suitable for this game?

Answer (score 4):

Check

***AnalogOnScreenControlExample.java*** [here](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AnalogOnScreenControlExample.java)

### Or

***DigitalOnScreenControlExample.java*** [here](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/DigitalOnScreenControlExample.java)

Comment: Aw man, wish I would have seen this sooner, could have saved a lot of time.